# How can I make the list of Open Files sticky in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Open Files is pretty handy, but scrolls out of view if I navigate to other files in the sidebar. Is there a way to make it stick so that as I scroll all files in the current directory the Open Files list stays within view on the top of the sidebar?

Answer (score -1):

This currently can't be done in Sublime Text, at least of time of writing (build 3120).

There might be a plugin available that does what you want, see [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search/open%20files).

You can also make a feature on the [forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com).